# Tensorflow error : Tensor.graph is meaningless when eager execution is enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

now I'm studying about tensorflow with jupyter notebook.

But, I have a problem.

my code like this!

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

print("sess.run(node1, node2): ", sess.run([node1, node2]))
print("sess.run(node3): ", sess.run(node3))
```

error occur like this.
**Tensor.graph is meaningless when eager execution is enabled.**
tenserflow version is 2.4.1. Do you konw how to solve this problem except changing version.
If you konw, then please teach me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable eager-execution.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```